# How to prevent Navbar dropdown from overlapping with rest of the content?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am using bootstrap 4 for a project.
When I toggle the navbar it overlaps with the content that follows it, how can I make the rest of the content move down to adjust for the dropdown?

I've added a 50px margin to my body.

I don't know why the snippet is displaying the header a little transparent.
This is how the site looks on my browser:

[image] 
[image]

```css
.row-header {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.navbar-dark {
  background-color: #512da8;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.row-content {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px ridge;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #d1c4e9;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.jumbotron {
  padding: 70px 30px 70px 30px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: #9575cd;
  color: floralwhite;
}

address {
  font-size: 80%;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #0f0f0f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">


    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/5.1.1/bootstrap-social.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mr-auto">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="./aboutUs.html" class="nav-link"><span class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span> Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="./contactus.html" class="nav-link"><span class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg"></span>
                            Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our
                        lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <h3>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm col-md">
                <h2>Uthappizza</h2>
                <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives,
                    ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <h3>This Month's Promotions</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm col-md">
                <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet</h2>
                <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers,
                    six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just
                    $19.99 per person </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <h3>Meet our Culinary Specialists</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm col-md">
                <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
                <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with
                    whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion
                    experiences. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 offset-1 col-sm-2">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./aboutUs.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./contactus.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                        121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                        Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                        HONG KONG<br>
                        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>: +852 1234 5678<br>
                        <i class="fa fa-fax fa-lg"></i>: +852 8765 4321<br>
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
                    </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="http://google.com/+" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google"><i
                                class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook"><i
                                class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin"><i
                                class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter"><i
                                class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a href="http://youtube.com/" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google"><i
                                class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a href="mailto:" class="btn btn-social-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <p>© Copyright 2018 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using `fixed-top` class. removing this might solve your problem. or you can try `off-canvas` menu.

Comment: You might have better luck with [sticky-top](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/position/#sticky-top), which doesn't take the navbar out of the flow of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navbar is overlapping the content below it after toggling because its position is fixed and it is aligned independent of the content below it, so in order to make it push the content below when it toggles you need to make it relative for small screen devices using media queries, something like

```
@media (max-width:480px){

    body{
        padding:0;
    }
    .fixed-top{
         position:relative;
    }

}
```

I made body padding `0` to make sure it doesn't show white space at top after navbar is made `relative`

But note that this will make your navbar to move up and away from viewport when page is scrolled down.